# Vue2 set a variable from an api callback

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this function return a call back as:

```
function fetchShifts(ctx, callback) {
const accountId = selectedAccount.value.value.id
store.dispatch('app-action-center/fetchShifts', {
  accountId,
})
  .then(shifts => {
    const data = []
    shifts.forEach(async (shift, index) => {
      const user = await store.dispatch('app-action-center/fetchUserDetails',
        {
          assignedTo: shift.assignedTo,
        })
        .then(res => res)
      data.push({
        ...shift,
        user: user.fullName,
      })
      if (index === (shifts.length - 1)) { callback(data) }
    })
  })
}
```

In the vue file I try to set it as:

```
data() {
 return {
   shifts: this.fetchShifts,
 }
},
```

or

```
data() {
 return {
   shifts: null,
 }
},
created() {
 this.shifts = this.fetchShifts()
}
```

None of them work, I want to make this shifts variable ready when the component mounted so I can put it in the `<app v-for="shift in shifts" />`

At this moment, this code work fine with `<b-table :items="fetchShifts />` but I don't know how to convert to `<ul v-for="shift in shifts></ul>`

Comment: Have you tried to inspect if `fetchShirts()` returns a promise or your code is sync?

Comment: It return an array of object I want when I put in in <app :items="fetchShifts" /> but I can't use it for v-for since v-for need an actual array not a callback

if in created() {console.log(this.fetchShifts())} it return a promise which has PromiseResult undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```html
<ul v-for="shift in shifts" :key="shift.id">
</ul>
```

```js
export default
{
  data()
  {
    return {
      shifts: [],
    };
  },
  created()
  {
    this.fetchShifts(undefined, (shiftsArray) =>
    {
      this.shifts = shiftsArray;
    });
  }
}
```

Explanation - initially you start with an empty array. Then you asynchronously fetch the shifts. The callback is called as soon as all the shifts and the corresponding users have been fetched - and in this callback you update the array with the shifts, which in turn triggers component re-rendering.

Vue is truly amazing!

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. I'd appreciate more if you have time to explain about the function :)